# Python EVE:- Blocking POST Method and Enabling PUT Method for some endpoints in Python EVE

Tags: python, web-services, eve

I initially wrote the `webservice` to allow the both 'GET' and `POST` methods to be allowed on all the endpoints . Now there are some changes in our webservices workflow , we want to block the `POST` endpoint for some of the endpoints and enable `PUT` for them some endpoints will still have `POST` enabled.

I will explain more by adding the code snippet of `settings.py`

```
__author__ = 'sappal'

# pulling DBSchema from DBTableSchema
from DBSchema.DBTableSchema import DBTableSchema
from Configs import Configs

dbtableSchema = DBTableSchema()


# Let's just use the local mongod instance. Edit as needed.
# Please note that MONGO_HOST and MONGO_PORT could very well be left
# out as they already default to a bare bones local 'mongod' instance.

## LOCALHOST ENTRIES
MONGO_HOST = Configs.MONGO_DB_HOST
MONGO_PORT = Configs.MONGO_DB_PORT
MONGO_USERNAME = Configs.MONGO_DB_USER_NAME
MONGO_PASSWORD = Configs.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD
MONGO_DBNAME = Configs.MONGO_DB

# Enable reads (GET), inserts (POST) and DELETE for resources/collections
# (if you omit this line, the API will default to ['GET'] and provide
# read-only access to the endpoint).
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE']

# Enable reads (GET), edits (PATCH), replacements (PUT) and deletes of
# individual items  (defaults to read-only item access).
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'POST']

# Used for implementing user-resource restricted access.
# Returns the documents which are associated with particular user

AUTH_FIELD = 'userid'

people = {
    'item_title': 'person',
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
    'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people,
    'public_methods': ['POST']
}

org = {
    'item_title': 'org',
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH'],
    'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_org
}

puburl = {
    'item_title': 'puburl',
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH'],
    'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_pub_url
}

address = {
    'item_title': 'address',
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH'],
    'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_address
}

contactnumber = {
    'item_title': 'contactnumber',
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH'],
    'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_contact_number
}

template = {
    'item_title': 'template',
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
    'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_template
}

usersharedcontacts = {
    'item_title': 'usersharedcontacts',
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH'],
    'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_with_user_shared_contacts
}

cardholder = {
    'item_title': 'cardholder',
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH'],
    'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_card_holder
}

DOMAIN = {
   'people': people,
   'org': org,
   'puburl': puburl,
   'address': address,
   'contactnumber': contactnumber,
   'template': template,
   'usersharedcontacts': usersharedcontacts,
   'cardholder': cardholder
}
```

I want to make `POST` method to be enabled for `people` and `template` endpoint, as you can see I have made this configuration `'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST']` for the above endpoints .

I also want to disable `POST` method for the remaining endpoints so I configured the following for those remaining endpoints `'resource_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH'],` .

I have also configured the  `RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE']`

But when I am trying to run the Application I am getting the errors on console of the following type

```
eve.exceptions.ConfigException: Unallowed [usersharedcontacts] resource    method(s): PATCH. Supported: GET, POST, DELETE

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: i need to ask a few questions. did you get this code working?

Comment: Applying @nicola's recommendation solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PATCH` is a document (item) method, not a resource method, that's why you get an Unallowed exception. Try with:

```
'resource_methods': ['GET'],  # read-only resource endpoint
'item_methods': ['PATCH']     # still allow edits at the document endpoint
```

See the [CRUD Operations](http://python-eve.org/features#full-range-of-crud-operations) table in the documentation for more details.

Comment: Although, the application does not break after this change, I have few more queries . I will post a follow up question around those issues .  :) , Thanks Nicola .